# Problem with doctrine command using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I've been trying to run the command php bin/console make:entity on my terminal on ubuntu but I have been getting this error message after trying to enter a property name and I have no idea what to do about it.

> In Validator.php line 158: Argument 2 passed to
> Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Validator::validateDoctrineFieldName() must
> be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry,
> instance of Doctrin     e\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called
> in
> /home/tautis/NQd/vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Maker/MakeEntity.php
> on line 303

Comment: Yes, we all are suffering on it. Doctrine released a new version where they replaced the ManagerRegistry with a Registry.  Setting "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6" helps with the error on the normal web frontend, but on console we seem have to wait. I reported it in the maker bundle: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665 - and doctrine says, they also fixed it on their side: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1202 - but with even this, the console cmd seems to be broken.